# Servlet with Ajax - POST works, but GET does not

Tags: java, javascript, ajax, servlets

I am making an application which would be able to count the numbers written in formulas. In html I have put this:

```
<input type="text" size="20" id="number2" onblur="validate2()"  
     onFocus = "document.getElementById('msg2').innerHTML = ' '">
<br>
<div id = "message1">&nbsp</div>
```

I have created a javascript which is firstly validating the datas and later inserts them into the 'answer-formula':

```
function validate2() {
var idField2 = document.getElementById("number2");
var data2 = "number2=" + encodeURIComponent(idField2.value);
if (typeof XMLHttpRequest != "undefined") {
    req = new XMLHttpRequest();
} else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
    req = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
var url = "Validator"
req.open("GET", url, true);        
req.onreadystatechange = inserter2
req.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")

;
    req.send(data2);
}

function inserter2() {
    if (req.readyState == 4) {
        if (req.status == 200) {
            var msg1 = req.responseText
            if (msg1 == "") {
                document.getElementById("message1").innerHTML = "<div style=\"color:red\">Zła nazwa</div>";
                document.getElementById("org").value = ''
            }
            else
                document.getElementById("org").value = msg2
        }
    }
}
```

And here's my code in which is sending it as doGet:

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    System.out.println("GET");

    response.setContentType("text/html");
    Writer out = response.getWriter();
    String num2 = request.getParameter("number2");
    System.out.println(num2);
    String org = new String();
    if(num2.matches("[\\p{Punct}\\d]+")) {
        ScriptEngineManager mgr = new ScriptEngineManager();
        ScriptEngine engine = mgr.getEngineByName("JavaScript");
        try {
            org = engine.eval(num2).toString() + " (" + request.getMethod() + ")";
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    out.write(org != null ?  org : "");
}
```

If we change all these things into the Post, this code will work, but now as it is with GET, it doesn't work at all. Another strange situation is that the formula with POST can read the written things in formula, but as we are using GET, the program see formula source as null.

Answer (score 1):

If you send it as get, you need to put formula into request. This expression:

```
req.send(data2);
```

doesn't make sense when you send GET request, as GET request cannot contain any payload except in request string. So you have to add payload to your url. Something like this:

```
var url = "Validator/?" + data2;
req.open("GET", url, true);        
req.onreadystatechange = inserter2;
req.send();
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: I have checked your code, but it doesn't work for me :(
Still the same issue.

Comment: Can you please share your app on github or something so I can play with it? I wasn't able to reproduce the issue, maybe it's hidden somewhere in the code, which not listed in the question.